# Custom properties (J2EEResourcePropertySet) of datasource do not appear when using UserDefined JDBC provider to create datasource trough wsadmin

Tags: jdbc, websphere, datasource, jython, wsadmin

So basically i have created user-defined JDBC provider through wsadmin:

```
AdminTask.createJDBCProvider('[-scope Cluster=MyCluster -databaseType User-defined -providerType "User-defined JDBC Provider" -implementationType User-defined -name "MSSQL JDBC Provider" -description "Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver" -classpath [${SQL_PATH}/sql.jar ] -nativePath "" -implementationClassName com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource ]')
```

After that i want to create datasource. So basically when i use UI to create datasource - it fills 3 pages with custom properties (J2EEResourcePropertySet) of that datasource (55 J2EEResourceProperties).

If i use wsadmin it does not fills those 3 pages for some reason only i see ~8 custom properties (J2EEResourceProperties).

If i look at log command assistance commands when creating trough UI and script - those are the same.

Can someone explain me what is wrong? I need to have 55 custom properties when running a script also. Thanks.

Here is my datasource script:

```
jdbcprovider = AdminConfig.getid('/JDBCProvider:MSSQL JDBC Provider/')
AdminTask.createDatasource(jdbcprovider, '[-name DataSource1 -jndiName DataSource1 -dataStoreHelperClassName com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.MicrosoftSQLServerDataStoreHelper -containerManagedPersistence true -componentManagedAuthenticationAlias SAmgr/DataSource1 ]')
```

Adding images to understand:

55 custom properties appeared:

[Creating datasource trough UI Custom Properties:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDVAf.png)

8 custom properties appeared:
[Creating datasource trough wsadmin script custom properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84j7f.png)

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, and the two line script snippet doesn't show me much.   Maybe show more of the wsadmin script explain in more detail what you're expecting to see that you're not?

Comment: Hi Scott, adding images to understand. 1st image is datasource created trough UI using same jdbc provider and it has 55 custom properties. 2nd image is datasource created trough that script which i pointed out it has only 8 custom properties. In Command assistance when i create it trough UI command is the same. Provider is also the same.
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDVAf.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/84j7f.png

Comment: OK, I understand better.  You're creating the provider via wsadmin but are concerned with the Admin Console UI view when later creating Datasources in the Admin Console.  So are you trying to create a custom JDBC provider which looks just like the MS SQL Server one for which WebSphere has a built-in template (all the same custom properties)?   Or are you trying to define a purely user-defined provider with all its own custom properties and have those properties appear in the Datasource view?

Comment: Yes im creating jdbc provider via wsadmin and its user-defined and im using different mssql driver for that (sqljdbc622.jar)
But the thing is that jdbcprovider creates fine. Then if i try to create datasource through UI using this user-defined provider i get custom properties added automatically (55 of them) if i use wsadmin to create datasource using this user-defined provider for some reason i do not get those 55 custom properties. I only get 8 of them. How do i fix it. I need to get 55 of them.

Comment: But the thing is that jdbcprovider creates fine. Even if i create jdbcprovider via UI it is same issue with datasource custom properties not appearing if i create datasource via wsadmin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:  When you create a DataSource using a JDBC provider created using one of the pre-defined types, like MS SQL Server JDBC Driver, WAS uses the contents of a template to populate (among other things) the properties of the datasource.  There is a template for both the 8 WebSphere properties (like webSphereDefaultQueryTimeout), and the other vendor-specific properties (like applicationName for MSSQL Server).  The 8 WebSphere specific properties are common to all datasources and are maintained by WAS and are not properties of the JDBC driver.  The properties in the vendor-specific template are a subset of all the vendor properties based on our assessment of whether it is “safe” to set/unset the property in a managed (JEE app server) environment.

Whether you create the datasource from the admin console or wsadmin, when the JDBC provider is based on one of the predefined vendors, the property set is the same since it’s coming from standard templates.  The behavior difference you're seeing is because you’re creating a user-defined JDBC provider and not using one of the predefined ones.  Typically, user-defined JDBC providers are only needed when the JDBC driver you want to use is not one of the pre-defined ones.  When you create a datasource from a user-defined JDBC provider using the admin console, behind the scenes it is calling a method to introspect the driver and discover any public javabeans that the JDBC driver exposes as properties. The admin console then adds these properties to the datasource in addition to the 8 WebSphere properties from the template discussed above.  The admin console performs the introspection because there is no template available for the vendor properties.  However, when you create a datasource from a user-defined JDBC provider using wsadmin, it doesn’t perform that introspection, thus the only properties you see on the datasource will be the 8 WebSphere properties from the template discussed above.  There are instances where the console executes some steps programmatically vs. via scripting and differences in behavior like this can arise. So, that's the answer to "why the difference”.  After investigation, there no option to have the wsadmin command introspect the driver adding the additional properties.
I see two ways you can address the issue and get the properties added.

If the set of driver properties you need is part of those included in the standard template for that driver, change from creating a user-defined JDBC provider to using one created with that driver vendor.  Using wsadmin, you’ll get all the same properties you would get if you created it from the admin console.  If some, but not all of the property(s) you need are in the template, you can add those properties via scripting using the AdminConfig.create(…) method as you suggested.  After your config is saved, all objects created via scripting will be available to see in the admin console, including the custom properties.

Comment: Thanks Fred ! That's explains everything.
p.s if there is no way to somehow call a method to introspect the driver and discover any public javabeans that the JDBC driver exposes as properties then its ok for me to configure all the custom properties via AdminConfig as example:
AdminConfig.create('J2EEResourceProperty', propSet, '[[name "databaseName"] [type "java.lang.String"] [description ""] [value "my_value"] [required "false"]]')
But then with one property i have issue. If there will be no way to make those custom properties appear i will raise one more question about that property.